# Need Help in retrieving data value from firestore

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

i would like to retrieve a data from firestore, but i cant seems to retrive it.

inside my user.ts provider

```
getUserEventData() {
  var sDoc = this.afs.doc(`users/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}`).collection('events').doc('volunteer');
  sDoc.snapshotChanges().forEach(element => {
    return element.payload.data;
  });
}
```

firestore indexing

[I want to retrieve the name/value of "Bandar Ku Ceria" imageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik6bE.png)

how I call it on profileUser.ts

```
console.log(this.userProvide.getUserEventData);
```

i want the "Bandar Ku Ceria" to be shown on the console for now, in a provider user.ts, am i using the right way to call data from firestore? help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the firestore docs again: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Your syntax seems to be coming from the Realtime Database and things has changed.

you cannot do doc(users/id) as you could in the Realtime Database.
you have to do 
db.collection('users').doc(USER_ID).collection('events').doc('volunteer')

And if you want to just the data once .get().then()... or if you need realtime updates

```
.onSnapshot(snap => {
//deal with the snapshot
})
```

Comment: hello thanks for replying, im relatively new to ionic, .get.then wont work, .doc('volunteer').get().then() have red underline under .get

Comment: ionic is javascript, no? So .get().then() should work.
db.collection('users').doc(USER_ID).collection('events').doc('volunteer').get().then(snap => {//you have your snapshot here})